# Drop rows from dataframe based on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched SO but have not found something similar to what I want to do. Basically, I have a dataframe like this:

```
Cod_BMF
Q20
R209
U20
R10
V20
R211
Z20
...
F26
R253
N26
R254
...
```

And I would like to pick from how many years forward (today is 20) to start dropping rows if they don't belong in a list. Everything that starts with R should also be kept.

To be more concrete, if `list = ['Q', 'F']` and `yearsfwd = 5`, I would like to drop everything with `"26"` that does not start with a letter from the list. So for my example, the df would be like this:

```
Cod_BMF
Q20
R209
U20
R10
V20
R211
Z20
...
F26
R253
R254
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas, use the **apply** method to remove rows based on multiple criteria.

Using the apply function seems to work:

```
list=['Q', 'F']
yearsfwd=5

dfNew = dfx.loc[dfx['Cod_BMF'].apply(lambda x: (x.startswith(tuple(list)) | (x[1:] != str(21 + yearsfwd))))]
```

-- Update --

This will remove rows where year >= yearsfwd in the dataset.

```
dfx.loc[dfx['Cod_BMF'].apply(lambda x: (x.startswith(tuple(list)) | (int(x[1:]) < (20 + yearsfwd))))]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Will try that in the morning.

Comment: Hey Mike. Sorry I probably did not say this in my question, but I want to drop 26, 27, 28, 29, etc when I put yearsfwd=5. Meaning I want to start dropping from 26 but not only that. I managed to get around this by doing a for loop like this:

`
for i in range(10):
    df = df .loc[df ['Cod_BMF'].apply(lambda x: (x.startswith(tuple(list)) | (x[1:] != str(20 + i + yearsfwd))))]
`

But I know this is not the most efficient way. It works for me because I will never have more than 15 years ahead. Any better ways?

Comment: You can use this code to remove all entries greater than 25, but it removes higher numbers also (209, 211, ...)   
`dfx.loc[dfx['Cod_BMF'].apply(lambda x: (x.startswith(tuple(list)) | (int(x[1:]) < (20 + yearsfwd))))]`